# What happens if a 12V battery is constantly exposed to a 12V power supply?

Tags: battery-charging

If a 12 volt battery is exposed to 12 volts for a long time would it overcharge the battery and harm it, or would the battery be unaffected, and not charge at all since there is no "additional" voltage over the battery's rated volts?

Edited to provide further context:

The battery chemistry I'm referencing is a lead acid battery that is "really" rated for 12.6 volts.

Comment: It depends on which kind of battery you mean, and whether the 12V is more closer to battery being full or empty or something in between, and how much you expect capacity out of it. Also, a 12V power supply is not a battery charger and may be damaged by connecting it to a battery. Do you have a specific type of power supply or a battery in mind, like NiMH, NiCd, lead-acid, etc?

Comment: @Justme Edited my question to provide that information.

Comment: You can't charge a 12V lead acid battery with just 12V. You will drastically reduce the lifetime of the battery and it will only reach a state of charge of around 50%. As you should not discharge a 12V battery very much below 50% before damaging it, you will essentially have no capacity left.

Comment: @StarCat I'm not looking to charge the battery with the power supply. The battery has a separate charger, just asking if I can have a battery and a supply hooked up at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lead acid can be float charged indefinitely at the recommended voltage; typically 13.4V.  Check your battery datasheet for exact numbers.

Note you will need a current-limited and slightly voltage-adjustable "12V" supply to do this.  Current limiting is required to prevent overtemp or failure when connecting a discharged battery, and to limit maximum charge rate per the datasheet.

Comment: Important to note that this is *only* true of lead-acid. NiMH can be float charged for a while but I'm pretty sure not indefinitely, and Li-ion of any sort absolutely cannot be float charged at all.

Comment: @Hearth: Are you sure about float charging Li-ion batteries? I think, a voltage close to the voltage of the unconnected full cell is not critical or reduces capacity.

Answer (score 4):

13.8V is the full charge for a 12V lead acid. So once it charged up to 12V (or if the battery and charger survived the battery catastrophically discharging down to 12V) it would just sit there partly charged. No current flow except to make up for the self-discharge from sitting on the shelf..

Answer (score 3):

Given that your battery is a nominal 12V lead acid battery, it will be fine.

Under ideal conditions the battery would maintain a constant charge of 12V and no current would flow into or out of the battery. (This assumes that current can flow into your 12V supply as well as outta of it.).

In reality, as temperatures change and as parts age, the "strength" of the battery and your external power supply will vary, and some current will probably flow to keep the voltages in balance.

This flow of current is unlikely to seriously affect the lifetime of the battery however. Lead acid batteries have a shelf life even without use, and they are typically designed to have their normal lifespan in an automobile, where they are exposed to the output of a regulated alternator for a significant portion of that lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

A state-of-the-art lead-acid charger actually has a 3-tier charge curve, designed to avoid stressing or overcharging the battery.  The ideal float voltage depends on the lead-acid construction.  However, car alternators and backup chargers are designed to "charge through" and continue charging a battery simultaneous to loads drawing power off the battery.

If you have a battery, battery charger and 12.0 volt power supply all in parallel, here's how that works.  The system will have a high quiescent voltage around 14V (varying by calibration of battery charger). As you add load, the voltage is going to fall somewhat.  That voltage will be the arbiter of which supply(ies) delivers the current.

If the system voltage is higher than a power supply's output voltage (i.e. 12.0 volts), that power supply will not deliver any current at all.

If the battery charger can carry the full load, it will keep charge voltage above the battery voltage and the load will run off the charger. Your car literally does this everytime you drive.

If the load is too much for the charger, then the voltage will fall further and current will be split between charger and battery. This is why solar systems work much better with a battery.